# php for each loop find lowest value

Tags: php, foreach

There are several options for one item. I.e. Item1 --> Option1: black, white, pink Option2: Small, Medium, Large --> each option is either available(1) or not available(0).

So if someone chooses Item1 with color black and size small the status should be returned based on availability.

My code is the following:

```
foreach ($item['option'] as $option) {
if ($option['availability']=0) { echo 'Not available'; } else { echo 'Available'; } }
```

So far so good. My problem is that I only want to print the status message only once, because the item with the configuration is either available or unavailable. With the above code I get twice the echo 'Not available' if both options in the example above are unavailable. I only would like to print :Not available' only once even if several options are unavailable. How can that be achieved?

I hope my question/problem is clear. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can [**break;**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) the loop (btw: `=` is an assignment, not comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use '==' because you are comparing the values and you can use break to stop the loop.

```
foreach ($item['option'] as $option) {
        if ($option['availability']==0) { 
            echo 'Not available'; 
            break; 
        } else { 
            echo 'Available'; 
            break;
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break; the loop or just exit it, exit;.

(This had to be a answer as i am not able to put it as a comment*

Comment: Develop the idea to a complete answer, including code if needed; if it is upvoted you accumulate reputation that will allow you to add comments :-)

Comment: Check the help centre: If you're unable to comment (because you haven't unlocked the privilege yet), don't post comments as answers. Wait until you _can_ comment, and rank up by posting actual answers. Comments-as-answers are very likely to get down-voted, so that way you'll never end up unlocking the comment privilege